# Changing behavior of Windows 8 Win+Space language changer

Tags: windows-8, input-languages

I wonder if it is possible to have <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> language changer act as Mac OS one.

In Mac OS it orders input languages by last used time, but in Windows 8 it just cycles between all of currently selected input languages without changing their order.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot, but you can at least order the languages to your liking:

[image]

That would require multiple keypresses to get back to the one you were using before. However you can use <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+                 to cycle backwards. So if you order the languages so that the two you most often switch between are up top you can just use <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+                 to switch once and <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+                 to switch back.

You can *also* access the old hot key options by clicking "Advanced settings" in the sidebar of the Language settings:

[image]

And then "Change language bar hot keys:

[image]

Here you can at least set hot keys for switching *to* certain languages/layouts just like before (and get rid of that annoying <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd> hot key):

[image]

Comment: That's bad, I really don't want to have 2 languages that can be used to input English at the same time. And switching to one takes you to cycle between 2 of them, switching to another makes you to do only one switch. It gets annoying really fast.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you just tried telling me.

Comment: I'm trying to ask one more question right now that tells about underlying problem. It is a bit complicated.

Comment: See the latest edit, maybe that is of some help.

Comment: I knew about switching to certain layouts\input methods. This is an option, although you still need to get used to it.

Comment: I once set that up and never used it again, so I know what you mean. But I still consider Win+Space a much better option than Alt+Shift ever was, so it's at least an improvement.

Comment: I hit some sort of bug with switching to certain layouts that stopped me using that feature. I don't remember certainly what it was, but it didn't work at all in some cases.

Comment: I liked the way it worked in Windows 7, where this shortcut was previewing the desktop. Isn't this possible in Windows 8?