# Disable input language on the default display language in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language, display-settings, input-languages

I've been looking for an answer for this for a long time and the closest I've found is [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/502658/complicated-input-language-and-display-language-setup-in-windows-8) however there's no satisfactory answer in there. I have almost an identical situation:

I use Swedish and Japanese as my input language and want to keep English as my display language. Since I can write English with my Swedish input method I don't need the English input. It becomes a hassle to switch between the input methods because I need to remember when I do the Win Key + Space (or left shift whichever you prefer) twice and when to do it once, resulting in me typing in the incorrect input method, resulting in me becoming annoyed over how such a simple setting becomes overly complicated, making me feel sad.

However, Windows 10 does not allow me to do this, it's an all-or-nothing approach. Either you have the display language *and* keep it in the input list, or you don't have it at all.

If I try to remove the English as input language (Language settings --> Region & Language --> Remove the English input) it also removes it as the display language:

**1. Language setting with English as display language**
[image: Language setting with English as display language]

**2. Removing English as input language**
[image: Removing English as input language]

**3. Display language is also removed**
[image: y u do dis]

**My goal:** 
Keep English as the display language, have *only* Swedish and Japanese as input methods.

**Question:** Is this possible and if so, how do I go about setting this? It seems like a very simple thing, yet I haven't found any setting that allows me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you search for is under Advanced settings:

[image: Screenshot of Advanced settings]

Comment: How would you configure this for Windows 11? I have the same situation as OP and don’t seem to be able to remove the English/US keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The direct registry setting to disable the keyboard layout toggle hotkeys is:

```
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Layout Hotkey" /d 3
```

You might also want

```
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Language Hotkey" /d 3
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Hotkey" /d 3
```

And for new users, try this (in an elevated prompt):

```
reg load HKEY_USERS\temp "%USERPROFILE%\..\Default\NTUSER.DAT"
reg add "HKEY_USERS\temp\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Layout Hotkey" /d 3
reg unload HKEY_USERS\temp
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. Part of writing a good answer is including explanation of what the listed steps do, this is not present in your answer. Please edit your answer to explain what each of the registry edits does, so people can decide whether or not they want to perform the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually change the taskbar input language list by editing the registry:

Press windows and type "regedit" and navigate to HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload.
There you will see a key for each language in the input list, but instead of names each language has a code, eg
00000409 - US English
00000c0a - Spanish,
Just google the codes you see to determine which is what, then delete the key you don't want.

The languages are numbered, so I suppose if you delete a key in the middle, it would be safer to rename the following keys so that the numbers remain sequential.

Then log off / restart to see the change.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the goal mentioned above, you can just add more keyboards to the "display language" by clicking on your first preferred language (under "Region & Language") and clicking on "Options".

In the next screen you can add more keyboards under the section "Keyboards".

This solution definitely achieves it's goal, hope this works for you and someone else! Cheers!