# Windows 11: How to remove English as an input language, but keep as display language and preferred language?

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages, regional-settings

This is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1046832/disable-input-language-on-the-default-display-language-in-windows-10), but for Windows 11.

I would like to use English (US) as my display language and it should also be the preferred language for apps.
However, the PC should use the Norwegian regional settings (Norwegian time format etc.), and I want to use Norwegian and German as input languages.
But I don't want to use English as an input language since I can use the German and Swedish keyboard settings to type English.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to figure out how to remove English as an input language (from the language bar). I have already used the administrative settings to make English (display language)/Norwegian/Norwegian the default settings for the welcome screen and new accounts, but that didn't help either.

How can I achieve that in Windows 11? All guides talk about removing the English language pack, but that's obviously not what I want. I want to be able to switch back and forth between the German and Norwegian keyboard, but Windows/apps should be displayed in English.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. This has always worked fine. I don't think you understood the question. It's only about removing a keyboard from the language bar that isn't needed.

Comment: You're right about that ;) On the question itself, doesn't the solution provided for your Windows 10 linked question work also for Windows 11? If not, what are the differences? Please use [edit] to update the question when applicable.