# How to set input language shortcuts on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, macos-catalina, automator

**Problem**

- I regularly use at least 3 languages, so I have the standard shortcut for switching the layouts (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>). This works well if there are only 2 languages, EN->RU
  and RU->EN, for example.
- Recently, I started using Japanese on top of it, which means that I have to keep switching between 4-5 layouts, which is a lot of cmd+space to press.
- I want to assign a separate shortcut to a specific layout.
- For example, for switching between RU and EN, I use cmd+space, and when I use a special shortcut like <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> I switch to Japanese layouts. I don't want it displayed by default in the language options:

  [image: Screenshot of what I am looking for.]

**Details**

- I'm on MacOS Catalina, and I couldn't find a way to attach a specific shortcut to one specific layout.
- There has been a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/502658/complicated-input-language-and-display-language-setup-in-windows-8) about Windows 8, but it didn't give me an idea how to port this on macOS.

**Possible solutions**

- Use Automator to solve such a problem? However, I am not sure what exactly to script there.