# Remove invisible language modes in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages

this might be considered a duplicate of my previous question: [Disable [Windows]+[Space] hotkey in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/581905/disable-windowsspace-hotkey-in-windows-8)
However my problem is more about getting rid of 2 settings, that should be removed, while they stay on keyboard layout selection indicator when I press `[WIN]`+`[SPACE]`. If I have ony one language set, accidentally pressing `[WIN]`+`[SPACE]` won't be a problem anymore.

I have only one language on languages list:
[image: Language settings window]

However I have 3 options when pressing `[WIN]`+`[SPACE]` or clicking `input indicator` icon in `notification area`.

[image: Layout selecting indicator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Languages, and then there are Input Methods.

If you only have one language installed, but more than one input method, then Win+Space lets you toggle between input methods.

To get rid of extra Input Methods:

In the Languages Control Panel applet, click "Options" next to the installed language.

[image]

`Remove` any extra 'Input Methods'.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the problem was, that, oddly - when I first removed some input methods and languages, they didn't disappear from what I call a `input indicator`. So the solution was to add them and remove again. +1 for images.

Answer (score 2):

I could not follow these steps because I've had just one language and input method.

But Windows was still showing two language options in notification area.

Then I added the language that was appearing unduly and then removed it again.

That solved the problem.

Comment: For me this unfortunately solves the problem only for a short while. Starting specific applications causes the second layout to return...

Answer (score 1):

I found a way without removing it from registry. I had to

1. Add all languages you have on `input indicator` (here `POL`)
2. Go to main (default; the only one I want to have left) language Options, and add all keyboard layouts I have on the `input indicator` (here `US keyboard`).
3. Save changes and make sure main language and keyboard layout are currently set.
4. Remove keyboard layouts and languages added a moment ago.