# Disable Windows + Space hotkey in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

**Not** a duplication of [Disable [Windows]+[Space] hotkey in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/581905/disable-windowsspace-hotkey-in-windows-8)

The question and answers in the link above talked about removing the input methods to stop switching of the methods. I differ because I want to KEEP the input methods. But remove/disable/prevent the [Windows]+[Space] hotkey for toggling them.

I have two Inputs Methods. (Two keyboard layouts in fact), The Standard UK layout, and created a second keyboard layout, I have called it ABC Layout, but its actually just a bunch extra symbols like copyright and a large number of other such symbols.

There is a Hotkey in windows 8.. Its [Windows]+[Space].. I would like to disable this.
This hotkey toggles between the two Inputs.. Sounds convenient, but it really is not. I don't know how or when, but it seems I sometimes hit this Hotkey without wanting to and end up with all sorts of gack on the screen if I am reading something off a second screen/paper.

I have gone into the logical location in the settings that deal with input and language control and the Hotkeys that deal with them. As you can see in the picture I had supplied, I have already removed the Hotkey for toggling [Please see image below], but Pressing [Windows]+[Space] still toggles the Input Mode.

[image: No Hotkey]

It seems in Win8, they have these options, but then just ignore them and do whatever it wants 
anyway as I have ALSO set language bar to be Hidden. But as you can clearly see in the screenshot, it's still there.

[image: Hidden Selected]
[image: Still Showing]

Comment: @Ramhound: I have re-ordered the question, Kinda did a mismash between my edits and original message. I also added a brief explanation of why. I didn't originally add this because I have been downvoted before on StackOverflow for it being irrelevant but maybe SuperUser prefer it. We will see.

Comment: I appreciate you removing the nonconstructive statements in your question. I still disapprove of the question itself, but to be honest, its not worth being disrespected on a site I love so I simply removed the downvote. I won't return to this question.

Comment: @WORMSS Don't take Ramhound too seriously. I'm not sure what his problem is, exactly, but there's definitely something going on there that's not worth getting too close to.

Comment: @WORMSS Why do you want to disable the hotkey?

Comment: @Firee I've listed the reason in my question already.

Comment: AFAIK you can't selectively disable the Win+Space keyboard shortcut (you can [disable some through an undocumented registry value](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/shell/explorer/globalhotkeys.htm), but not all of them), and disabling the left/right Windows key (or both) entirely wouldn't be a feasible solution.

Comment: @WORMSS Have you tried setting a *different* hotkey? It may fall back to Windows-Space if none is set, but if you set a different one, it may release the default.

Comment: @maxx daymon yes, still changes, even tried a restart, no go.

Comment: @WORMSS You can disable *all* the Win+X keyboard shortcuts, which would solve your problem, but it may result in losing more shortcuts than you wanted. The problem is coming from the bi-polar nature of Windows 8 in that the Win+Space shortcut is coming from "Metro", and the settings you are looking at are "Desktop"

Comment: I have my input methods Dvorak and QWERTY layout and this gets switched accidentally far too often if Windows+Space is active.  This didn't use to be the case in Windows 7. Windows 8.x introduces far too many annoyances such as this and really really sucks

Comment: Remove one of the two languages and the hotkey + icon will be removed. Settings -> Time & Language -> Region & Language Just one language shown? First reinstall the second language and then remove it again. This solved my identical case.

Comment: By that logic, I could get rid of the problem by uninstalling Windows.. I need the second keyboard layout. (Hence why I have two in the first place). And it seems you have 2 languages, rather than 2 keyboard layouts for the same language. So not 'identical case'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's a natural way to do this from within Windows 8, but you can do it using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Download and run/install AutoHotKey, right click on some folder, then New>AutoHotKey Script. Edit that with Notepad or Notepad++ and add this hotkey:

```
#Space::
return
```

That remaps the Win(#)+Space(Space) button to do nothing. Then you just run the AutoHotkey Script. To get it to run automatically when your computer starts, put the script into the startup folder.

Hopefully autohotkey isn't too intrusive. Maybe you'll find some other uses for it (I think I first found out about it when I was trying to remap Caps-Lock so that it doesn't do anything, since that's the world's most pointless key).

Comment: Was reluctant to install this just for this situation, but feels so but better now not accidentally switching language. The only reason I installed language packs was for different TTS voices and it was driving me crazy when I ended up with the wrong language all the time.

Comment: This continues to be a working solution on Windows 11.

Comment: Never got get all the Caps Lock hate on the interwebs (it's probably some mob thing) , it quite a useful key to me. Then again, I'm the only person in the world who thinks Crocs are aesthetically pleasing, not just very high quality, functionally speaking ...

Comment: @GwenKillerby - This triggered me so hard. My partner loves crocs... And I HATE them (caps!) :/

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

- Install PowerToys.
- Enable "PowerToys Run".
- Change the hotkey to Windows+Space.
- Check the option "Use centralized keyboard hook".

Now you can enjoy having a mac-like search. You will not have to deal with the input accidentally changing, since this hotkey will override that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the windows + shortcut keys multiple ways:

Over windows registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoWinKeys"=dword:00000001
```

In group policy editor (gpedit.msc):

User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer -> Turn off Windows + X hotkeys

And you also can disable the windows key completely with Widnows Scancode Map feature. To do it, i recommend to download an open source application called [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

You can add new keymap, type the key (press win button), and select Turn Key Off option (see the picture bellow).

[image: sharpkeys win button remap]

Press write to registry button, and restart windows.

Comment: This seems like it turns off ALL [Win]+Key shortcuts. Not just a single one? So I couldn't do the useful [Win]+L to logout.

Comment: Yes, the solution above turn off ALL [Win]+Key based hotkeys. After that, the hotkeys function accessible only over UI, or custom shortcuts.


For example my lock screen shortcut based on this command: 
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

Comment: So you are saying.. for the 50 odd windows shortcuts that exist.. Turn them ALL off, and then Hack the 49 others back in?

Comment: All of my home computers built for special purposes (music making, gaming) the win key disabled completely. I never use any win hotkey on these computers, and the accidentally keyboard layout changes (win+space) always can create some mess. 
On my laptop (used during daily work in enterprise environment) i leave the win key on, because i frequently change keyboard layout, and lock the screen.
I think, it's purely personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of Pulover's MacroCreator and EventGhost. But you should be able to do this just using EventGhost.

The nice thing about EventGhost is that you can still use Windows+key shortcuts in another application so you don't need to disable the windows key completely.

For example, for the windows+space shortcut. You just need the keyboard plugin in Autostart, and a macro to emulate the win+space keystroke in the active application.

In the macro, you'll need the event (Keyboard.Win+Space), followed by an Emulate Keystrokes action, with the Text to type being {Win+Space}, and check the box for use alternate method to emulate keypresses.

http://www.eventghost.net/#download

I'd recommend using the stable 0.4 release since the 0.5 pre-release has some errors on startup that may cause problems.

[image]